# Add elements to a list that belongs to a state using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this json variable on my state:

```
this.state = {
        type:
        {
            name: '',
            type2: {
                atribute: '',
                parameter: [
                    {
                        value: '',
                        classtype: ''
                    }
                ],
                name: '',
                atribute1: '',
                atribute2: ''
            }
        }
    }
```

what I wanted to do is to add elements to my parameter list,which is empty on the beggining.

What I did was this:

```
addParams = () => {

    let newParam = {
        value: this.state.type.type2.parameter.value,
        classtype: this.state.type.type2.parameter.classtype
    };

    /** */
    this.setState(prevState => ({


        type: {

            // keep all the other key-value pairs of type
            ...prevState.type,

            type2: {

                ...prevState.type.type2,

                //this is supposed to add an element to a list
                parameter: [...prevState.type.type2.parameter, newParam]
            }
        }
    }))  
}
```

But when executing the last line of code the following error appeared:

> Uncaught TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance
>   when spreading a list

I do not know why this does not work because the parameter is a list indeed.

Answer (score 0):

If `this.state.type.type2.parameter` is an array then why are you referencing properties on it:

```
let newParam = {
    value: this.state.type.type2.parameter.value,
    classtype: this.state.type.type2.parameter.classtype
};
```

I don't think your state is structured how you expect, seems like you're replacing that array with an object at some point in your code. I suggest [react-devtools](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools) to help you keep track of your state as it changes.

This isn't exactly an answer but I highly suggest using [immerjs](https://github.com/immerjs/immer) for doing these pure nested updates. I almost never recommend adding a third party library as a solution but immer is lightweight and life changing. It exports a single function called produce and uses a concept called a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to perform pure updates that are written as mutations.

With immer (and your bug fixed) your code becomes this:

```
const newParam = {
    value: this.state.type.type2.parameter.value,
    classtype: this.state.type.type2.parameter.classtype
};

this.setState(produce(draftState => {
  draftState.type.type2.parameter.push(newParam);
}))
```

It lets you write more terse code that is a lot easier to read. And yes I know that **looks** like a mutation, but it isn't one this is 100% pure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 this.setState(prevState => {
        return {
            ...prevState,
            type: {
                ...prevState.type,
                type2: {
                    ...prevState.type.type2,
                    parameter: [...prevState.type.type2.parameter, newParam]
                }
            }
        }

    )
```